# SQL Server Configuration Manager won't start: WMI returns error

Tags: sql-server, wmi

We're trying to run SQL Server Configuration Manager and getting the error

```
Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager.
Access is denied. [0x80070005]
```

based on the article found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013), we have run

```
C:\Windows\system32>mofcomp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

and

```
C:\Windows\system32>mofcomp "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

but we're getting the error

```
Microsoft (R) MOF Compiler Version 6.3.9600.16384
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2006. All rights reserved.
Parsing MOF file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmprovide
rxpsp2up.mof
MOF file has been successfully parsed
Storing data in the repository...
An error occurred while processing item 10 defined on lines 73 - 79 in file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof:
Error Number: 0x80070005, Facility: Win32
Description: Access is denied.
Compiler returned error 0x80070005
```

We added the principal EVERYONE to with full permissions to the SQL Server root folder as well as the SQL Server SHARED folder. The SHARED folder has partial read-only status, but I prefer not to change that, because I can't set it back once this is done.

the file itself, sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof, is NOT read only.

This is a Windows Server 2012, not in a domain, and I ran CMD as administrator (although I am administrator anyway). UAS is turned off. SQL Server 2012 Express, 64 bit.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you find out anything with this?  Noticing this on Windows Desktop OS as well.

Comment: Same problem in Windows 2012R2 (DC) + SQL Serwer 2014.

Comment: Got the sme problem on Windows 10 and SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure winmgmt service is started**

Start a CMD as administrator and execute following command

```
net start winmgmt
```

also make sure the service is started automatically within

```
services.msc
```

Reference :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Run the CMD as Admin and run the command
C:\Windows\system32>mofcomp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
this would let the command run successfully

Comment: This is exactly what was already tried in the question.